RTR admin command not found (Real time response Admin)
I'm writing a python script to remove admin rights from the user using crowd strike RTR admin. And I'm getting the error : {'code': 40006, 'message': 'Command is not valid'}
command_string = f"Remove-LocalGroupMember -Group 'Administrators' -Member '{username}'"

response = falcon.execute_admin_command(base_command="run",
                                        command_string=command_string,
                                        session_id=session_id,
                                        persist=True)

I have not uploaded the script on crowdstrike instead tried running the command directly on host using both runscript and run base_command

Why is this tagged falcon?

This is a CrowdStrike falcon API

That's not what the falcon tag is for.

thank you for correcting me, I couldn't find any relevant tags for CrowdStrike falcon API

I couldn't find any relating to CrowdStrike at all!
